# Passing multiple scalar parameters to WebAPI via HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Here's my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("TestString")]
public string TestString([FromBody] int a, [FromBody] int b, [FromBody] int c)
{
  return "test " + a + " " + b + " " + c;
}
```

Is there any way that i can call this method using `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync`

I've tried this:

`HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/task/TestString","a=8,b=5,c=6").Result;`

But I get this error: `StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are only allowed a single [FromBody] tag. Try (add your own error handling etc):

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("TestString")]
public string TestString([FromBody] dynamic body)
{
  return "test " + body.a.ToString() + " " + body.b.ToString() + " " + body.c.ToString();
}
```

This should work provided that for form body actually contains a,b and c.

Comment: Thanks, but it just sends the whole string through "a=6&b=5&c=2"
and doesn't split out the variables. Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In answer to the question - no you cannot call your function (with anything) because it will always throw an Internal Server Error. You cannot have more than one [FromBody] attribute - it's not needed as the HTTP POST only has one body.